# Is it possible to create an app with only swift ?

Tags: swift, swift2

I've started to learn swift and it is told to be a very fast language who takes over the Objective-C. But at many times, I saw it is not enough to write only with Swift and it was need others languages. So I would know if with my MacBook, Xcode and Swift only, it's possible to create app like Snapchat, Instagram WhatsApp or other.

Thanks you.

Comment: Every thing is possible with Swift . My Friend

Comment: You can create any apps using swift but for backend technology would be different. You can make apps only using swift. @miguel

Comment: @iDeveloper **Almost** *Every thing ...*. For example for integrating AppleScriptObjC in a Swift app an Objective-C bridge is required.

Comment: @vadian, Sounds good

Comment: In the future, consider Googling first - a query for `Is it possible to create an app with only swift ?` has loads of results with great info

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should be possible that you will never have to touch anything else. But a lot of the made by Apple is running Objective-C or C.
But again when you start spending time on one programming language others start to seem more similar.

Comment: Thanks you for all guys !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can. You can use only Objc or only swift or you can mixed up both language.

First start learning swift and learn how to use APPLE API. Then get some idea of app and start developing.

Take look from these link and tutorial :

1. https://www.raywenderlich.com/143771/swift-tutorial-part-1-expressions-variables-constants
2. https://www.airpair.com/swift/building-swift-app-tutorial
3. http://codewithchris.com/how-to-make-an-iphone-app/
4. http://www.appcoda.com/learnswift/build-your-first-app.html
5. Specially look * (Download example on swift, learn coding technique and many other helps) :  https://github.com/search?l=Swift&q=swift+Tutorial&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93